# Getting information from Gmaps like grassland, street, water etc

Tags: php, html, google-maps

I'm thinking about a project, where I need such informations as described in the title. Does the Google Maps API provide something like this, or does anyone know how to get these informations?

Project will be done in PHP, HTML and Javascript.

Comment: How about OpenStreetMap? Not the same map source, but I think you might be able to get the data from their API: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API

Comment: The nice thing with Gmaps is: there's much stuff which is already done.

Comment: The not-so-nice thing with Gmaps is: there's much stuff which Google won't give to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Google doesn't provide this information via the API. The only thing I can think of is getting the image, and then detecting the colour. A map of colour hex values against point type might give you what you need.

However, this may well break the Terms and Conditions, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: IANAL and all that, but scraping tiles and extracting content is almost surely over the line - e.g. ToS items under 10.1.3: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

Comment: @Piskvor You are probably right, and I would strongly recommend reading the Ts and Cs before going down this route.